# How can I make a UIView fade from a solid background color to clear background color?

Tags: ios, swift

I know that there are multiple ways (CAAnimation, commitAnimations, etc), but what is the simplest way?

I'd like the UIView to start from blue and then fade to clear (or white, whatever is easier) in X milliseconds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `UIView`'s animation method. It's much simpler than the other animations, but is more limited. Luckily, `backgroundColor` is one of the animatable ones. Example:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
})
```

Comment: Agreed on using UIView animation. (Voted). Much simpler than CAAnimation.