# UITableView on scrolling up moves from front to behind

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

Below view is a `tableViewController` which is implemented and set the delegate and datasource methods and it works perfectly fine but I have no idea how to implement the purple view behavior on scrolling up and down.

How can I implement it?

The below code is the way I detect that view scrolled up or down. but still, no clue to implement this behavior.

```
override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let translation = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview)
    if translation.y > 0 {
        presenter?.viewScrolledDown()
    } else {
        presenter?.viewScrolledUp()
    }
}
```

[image: scrolling-view-up]

Comment: can show what code u have on scroll

Comment: Please show the code you have attempted and highlight the area you are having problems with.

Comment: Sorry for the very very brief explanation. i've updated the question.

Comment: @amirjam are you asking how to implement the animation? From your question it seems like you are able to detect when it is scrolling, you just need to write the animation. Is this correct?

Comment: @gmdev Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038974/how-can-i-make-a-uiview-fade-from-a-solid-background-color-to-clear-background-c/37039010) covers how to animate a `backgroundColor`. If the purple view is a `UIView`, this won't be a problem. It starts **behind** the `tableView` and then moves to the **front** of the `tableView.` You can handle this by using these functions:

```
view.bringSubviewToFront(purpleView)
view.sendSubviewToBack(tableView)
```

You will also need to animate the `autoLayout` constraints to move the bottom of the purple view up to the top of the `tableView`.